# How to deserialize rest response in jBPM

Tags: deserialization, jbpm

I am trying out jBPM as a candidate to redistribute requests to the one relevant service of multiple services.

The first thing I want to try is, connect to an internal data source and get some input to make a decision. I found out about Work Item Handlers and successfully grabed data via the org.jbpm.process.workitem.rest.RESTWorkItemHandler.

But now I have no clue how to deserialize the returned XML or CSV in order to make use of the data.